# Inc value in while loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to get a value from a listview and add 1 to the result for inclusion in access db. The problem is that if I add an inc statement like thus +1 it keeps changing it to use CDbl which gives me the incorrect result. Example, Before adding 1 it gives '011697' after adding 1 it gives '11697'. Why has it dropped the leading zero. The field is a text field so I am confused why it changes to CDbl. Can someone please help with this. Thanks

```
    Dim id As String

    While dr.Read()

          id = dr.Item(0).ToString
          id = CStr(CDbl(id) + 1)

    End While
```

Comment: when you convert  to double it automatic remove the left zero. if this zero is **constants** then you can do some String editing to keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the number to an integer, add the increment value and then reformat to a string of 6 numbers with the required leading zeros

```
Dim id As String
While dr.Read()
      id = dr.Item(0).ToString
      id = string.Format("{0:D6}", (Convert.ToInt32(id) + 1))
End While
```

The conversion to a number force the dismissing of the leading zero as it is meaningless in a number, using [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) restore the string with the required number of characters and filling the missing characters with zero

By the way, if it is possible, try to remove those function like CDbl and CStr. They are present just for easing the conversion of old VB6 apps. There are many alternative in NET and unless very special cases, these alternative are better than these VB6 compatibility functions.

Comment: Steve that errors with: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for that steve. Could I ask though, as a new user to vb.net, what exactly does "{0:D6}" mean.

Comment: See the link to the Composite Formatting topic on MSDN. Basically it means: Take the first argument (0) after the closing quotes and be sure to have at least 6 integer digits. If lesser digits are present fill the resulting string adding zero to the left.

Answer (score 1):

use this code if you want to keep the zero :

```
Dim id As String

While dr.Read()

      id = dr.Item(0).ToString
      id = CStr(CDbl(id) + 1)
      id = id.PadLeft(6, "0")
End While
```